# Replace string got from pipe in a file in command line

Tags: string, bash, command-line, replace, sed

How can I use `sed` or `tr` or `replace` to replace the string I get from pipe like:

```
head -n 1 myfile | sed -i 's/'-'/leg/g' new.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
MY_PAT=$(head -n 1 myfile)
sed -i "s/$MY_PAT/leg/g" new.log
```

or

```
sed -i "s/$(head -n 1 myfile)/leg/g" new.log
```

if your `myfile` contains special characters, better give concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

use the `read` shell builtin to get the first line from stdin.

```
#!/bin/bash
read TO_REPLACE
head -n 1 myfile | sed -i "s/$TO_REPLACE/leg/g" new.log
```